# Is there a way to check whether a related object is already fetched?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-select-related

I would like to be able to check if a related object has already been fetched by using either `select_related` or `prefetch_related`, so that I can serialize the data accordingly. Here is an example:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)

def serialize_address(address):
    return {
        "id": address.id,
        "street": address.street,
        "zip": address.zip
    }

def serialize_person(person):
    result = {
        "id": person.id,
        "name": person.name
    }
    if is_fetched(person.address):
        result["address"] = serialize_address(person.address)
    else:
        result["address"] = None

######

person_a = Person.objects.select_related("address").get(id=1)
person_b = Person.objects.get(id=2)

serialize_person(person_a) #should be object with id, name and address
serialize_person(person_b) #should be object with only id and name
```

In this example, the function `is_fetched` is what I am looking for. I would like to determine if the person object already has a resolves address and only if it has, it should be serialized as well. But if it doesn't, no further database query should be executed.

So is there a way to achieve this in Django?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the `address` relation has been fetched, then the Person object will have a populated attribute called `_address_cache`; you can check this.

```
def is_fetched(obj, relation_name):
    cache_name = '_{}_cache'.format(relation_name)
    return getattr(obj, cache_name, False)
```

Note you'd need to call this with the object and the name of the relation:

```
is_fetched(person, 'address')
```

since doing `person.address` would trigger the fetch immediately.

**Edit** reverse or many-to-many relations can only be fetched by `prefetch_related`; that populates a single attribute, `_prefetched_objects_cache`, which is a dict of lists where the key is the name of the related model. Eg if you do:

```
addresses = Address.objects.prefetch_related('person_set')
```

then each item in `addresses` will have a `_prefetched_objects_cache` dict containing a `"person'` key.

Note, both of these are single-underscore attributes which means they are part of the private API; you're free to use them, but Django is also free to change them in future releases.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising. Will it also work for ManyToMany relations or reverse ForeignKey relations? For instance: '_topping_set_cache'?

Comment: While this is the accepted answer, note that it no longer works in a more recent version of Django. `obj._state.fields_cache` seems like the way to go now.

Comment: This do not works for reverse m2m cache, if fetched using `Person.objects.prefetch_related('address').all()`.  Pre-fetched values available in `obj._state.fields_cache` for `.select_related('')`, but not for `.prefetch_related`. How django returns pre-fetched related objects from cache? Where it stores and do we have access to read it?

Answer (score 21):

Since **Django 2.0** you can easily check for all fetched relation by:

```py
obj._state.fields_cache
```

[`ModelStateFieldsCacheDescriptor`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/base/) is responsible for storing your cached relations.

```py
>>> Person.objects.first()._state.fields_cache
{}
>>> Person.objects.select_related('address').first()._state.fields_cache
{'address': <Address: Your Address>}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I created a Django ticket to see if this attribute should be considered public or private (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31803)

Answer (score 6):

Per [this comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31803#comment:2) on the ticket linked in the comment by @jaap3 above, the recommended way to do this for **Django 3+** (perhaps 2+?) is to use the undocumented `is_cached` method on the model's field, which comes from [this internal mixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d8c90d4c22cb218f1c170eba086c53d3dff7fbc0/django/db/models/fields/mixins.py#L21-L22):

```py
>>> person1 = Person.objects.first()
>>> Person.address.is_cached(person1)
False

>>> person2 = Person.objects.select_related('address').last()
>>> Person.address.is_cached(person2)
True
```