# Invalidate Django cached_property in signal handler without introducing unnecessary queries

Tags: python, django, caching

Let's say I have the following Django models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="TeamUser")

    @cached_property
    def total_points(self):
        return self.teamuser_set.aggregate(models.Sum("points"))["points__sum"] or 0

class TeamUser(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to create a signal handler that will invalidate the `team.total_points` cache when `TeamUser` object is created/updated/deleted.

I started with the following signal handler. Note the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) recommended the `del instance.prop` call.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=models.TeamUser)
@receiver(post_delete, sender=models.TeamUser)
def invalidate_cache(**kwargs):
    try:
        del kwargs["instance"].team.total_points
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

And some tests. Note I'm using pytest-django.

```
def test_create_team_users(django_assert_num_queries):
    user = factories.UserFactory()
    team = factories.TeamFactory()
    assert team.total_points == 0

    with django_assert_num_queries(1):
        TeamUser.objects.create(team=team, user=user, points=2)
    assert team.total_points == 2

    with django_assert_num_queries(1):
        TeamUser.objects.create(team=team, user=user, points=3)
    assert team.total_points == 5

def test_delete_all_team_users(django_assert_num_queries):
    user = factories.UserFactory()
    team = factories.TeamFactory()
    for _ in range(10):
        TeamUser.objects.create(team=team, user=user, points=2)

    with django_assert_num_queries(2):
        TeamUser.objects.all().delete()
    assert team.total_points == 0
```

The `test_create_team_users` test passed but the `test_delete_all_team_users` test failed  because the query count is 12 instead of 2. Yikes! Looks like an N+1 query.

To prevent this, I updated my signal handler to only invalidate the `team.total_points` cache if the user object is cached on the `TeamUser` object. I found the `is_cached` method in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68200269/6611672).

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=models.TeamUser)
@receiver(post_delete, sender=models.TeamUser)
def invalidate_cache(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if sender.team.is_cached(instance):
        try:
            del instance.team.total_points
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Now both tests pass!

Does this correctly invalidate the `team.total_points` cache in all cases? Is there an edge case I'm missing?

Comment: Could bulk operations (i.e. `bulk_create()`, `update()`, or `delete()`) be a concern? Each of those operations side-steps custom calls to `save()`, and no signals get emitted. Good question, by the way.

Comment: The cache for ```the tem.total.points``` of a ```TeamUser``` instance is updated through a signal handler using Django's signals when the instance is saved or deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a misconception here. cached_property isn't actually a persisting database cache or a Redis cache. It lives and dies within one instance. This usually means a single request. It will be already refreshed in the next request.

It's reason for existence is to not call an expensive method more than once, within the same instance.

For example, if you had a template that used this team.total_points next to a team's name, but also around footnotes and maybe as html title attribute for the picture so that it shows when you hover over team's picture, with @property, this method would get called 3 times, with @cached_property, this method would only get called once.

But it's not going to last for the next request or next page refresh. So "invalidating" it in a signal is most possibly unneeded.

Not only unneeded but it won't even work for some cases. This would fail for example:

```py
def test_delete_all_team_users(django_assert_num_queries):
    user = factories.UserFactory()
    team = factories.TeamFactory()
    for _ in range(10):
        TeamUser.objects.create(team=team, user=user, points=2)

    # this assert will pass, but while doing it, total_points will be cached
    assert team.total_points == 20
    with django_assert_num_queries(2):
        TeamUser.objects.all().delete()
    # this will fail now because team.total_points was cached before and the cache isn't cleared
    assert team.total_points == 0
```

This is because "instance.team" in the post_delete callback isn't the same team instance as the one you have in the test function. These are separate team instances that are populated by the same database row.

So a signal can't work here to delete this cache. It's useless. Instead of a post_delete signal here, you should delete team.total_points within the test function itself, after deleting TeamUsers or before asserting. Then it would pass.

```py
def test_delete_all_team_users(django_assert_num_queries):
    user = factories.UserFactory()
    team = factories.TeamFactory()
    for _ in range(10):
        TeamUser.objects.create(team=team, user=user, points=2)

    assert team.total_points == 20
    with django_assert_num_queries(2):
        TeamUser.objects.all().delete()

    del team.total_points
    # this will pass now
    assert team.total_points == 0
```

This too would pass with the signal because django is populating instance.team with the same team instance as the one you have in the test function in here.

```py
def test_delete_all_team_users(django_assert_num_queries):
    user = factories.UserFactory()
    team = factories.TeamFactory()
    for _ in range(10):
        TeamUser.objects.create(team=team, user=user, points=2)

    assert team.total_points == 20
    with django_assert_num_queries(2):
        team.teamuser_set.all().delete()
        # TeamUser.objects.all().delete()

    # this will pass too. because signal cleared the cache this time.
    assert team.total_points == 0
```

I should also say that post_delete signal here is also costing you an extra database hit. if you get rid of it, TeamUser.objects.all().delete() should only hit your database once, instead of twice. But you would need to manually delete the cache after you do something that will change it. Besides the test functions, it will very rarely occur so I don't think it'll be much of a miss.

Edit:

This is not only for deleting but if you are not passing the team instance itself, but passing an id of it perhaps, post_save signals won't work as you expect either.

This too will fail:

```py
def test_create_team_users(django_assert_num_queries):
    user = factories.UserFactory()
    team = factories.TeamFactory()
    assert team.total_points == 0

    with django_assert_num_queries(1):
        # I changed this so that we're passing team_id instead of team
        # In post_save, team instance will be different.
        TeamUser.objects.create(team_id=team.id, user=user, points=2)
    # so this assert will fail
    assert team.total_points == 2
```

Comment: All in all. I'm seeing that invalidating cached properties using signals is unreliable. On top of that, signals don't run for some operations (`bulk_create` and `bulk_update`). So I'm probably not going to rely on signals to invalidate my cache. I'll just invalidate the cache at the call sites.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise *not* to use a cached property or signals, and just calculate the points when needed by a query. We can do this with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Team.objects.annotate(total_points=Coalesce(Sum('teamuser__points'), Value(0)))
```

and thus remove the `total_points` cached property.

the `Team` objects that arise from *this* `QuerySet` will then have an extra attribute with the `.total_points` that is the sum of the `points` of the *related* `TeamUser`s. The nice thing is that this will all be done in the *same* query where we *fetch* the `Team` objects, for all `Team` objects, so even if we obtain hundred of `Team`s, it calculate the total points in the same query where we fetch the details of the `Team`s.

Using signals however is often a *bad* idea, especially since there are several scenario's where signals *don't* run. This is the case for [**`.bulk_create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) and [**`.bulk_update(…)`** queries <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) for example: then no signal is triggered, and thus the cache is never invalidated. I wrote an article on the [problems with *signals* <sup>[django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html) that aims to summarize why signals should only be used as a last resort, if all else failed: there are scenario's where the signals don't get triggered, and this thus means that the `Team`'s `.total_points` will be wrong.

It thus is better simply *not* to assume that we have the latest number of points, but if we can fetch the `Team` details together with the number of points, even for a single team with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Team.objects.annotate(
    total_points=Coalesce(Sum('teamuser__points'), Value(0))
).get(pk=some_pk)
```

it is not much of a problem, since we simply can fetch the total number of points in one query for that (or a set of) `Team`s.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, so far I can tell your updated signal handler will correctly implemented the `team.total_points` cache in all cases. The reason for the N+1 query in your original signal handler is that the `del instance.team.total_points` call is actually deleting the `total_points` attribute from the `TeamUser` object, not from the cache. By checking if the user object is cached on the `TeamUser` object before deleting the `total_points` attribute, you ensure that the only time the cache is invalidated is when the `total_points` value has actually changed. This prevents the N+1 query.

Tips for invalidating cache in Django:

- Use the cached_property decorator to cache expensive computations. This will automatically invalidate the cache whenever the underlying data changes.
- Use the cache.invalidate() function to manually invalidate cache entries. This can be useful for invalidating cache entries that are not associated with a specific model object.
- Use a Django signal handler to invalidate cache entries when model objects are created, updated, or deleted. This is a good way to ensure that the cache is always in sync with the database.

I hope this is helpful!